# Change sprite at each new location

Tags: sprite-kit

Using SpriteKit, 
is there an event that is fired each time the sprite is placed at a new location on the screen?

What i need to accomplish is to change the sprite based on the direction the sprite is moving to.

I was thinking that each time the collision detection event is fired would be a good place to change the sprite??

Comment: nope, contact delegate messages occur too infrequent. Use the update: method of the scene, forward it to your sprite, and do your calculations there.

Comment: Hi Steffen...  thanks for the reply, but i am lost...  where is the update method of the screen?

Comment: scene, not screen .. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKScene/update:

Comment: right - sorry...   typo   thank you